# Can you recommend an Amazon AMI for Python?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I want to remove as much complexity as I can from administering Python in on Amazon EC2 following some truly awful experiences with hosting providers who claim support for Python.  I am looking for some guidance on which AMI to choose so that I have a stable and easily managed environment which already included Python and ideally an Apache web server and a database.

I am agnostic to Python version, web server, DB and OS as I am still early enough in my development cycle that I can influence those choices.  Cost is not a consideration (within bounds) so Windows will work fine if it means easy administration.

Anyone have any practical experience or recommendations they can share?

Answer (score 4):

Try the [Ubuntu EC2 images](http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/release/). Python 2.7 is installed by default. The rest you just `apt-get install` and optionally create an image when the baseline is the way you want it (or just maintain a script that installs all the pieces and run after you create the base Ubuntu instance).

Answer (score 2):

If you can get by with using the Amazon provided ones, I'd recommend it. I tend to use ami-84db39ed.

Honestly though, if you plan on leaving this running all the time, you would probably save a bit of money by just going with a VPS. Amazon tends to be cheaper if you are turning the service on and off over time.

Comment: I'm open to that, any recommendations for VPS providers?

Comment: I would check out Slicehost and Linode, I've had good experiences with both.  Both offer multiple distro choices.  I am personally using Linode at the moment.